# Set timeout on Django View Execution

Tags: django, django-views

How can I set a time limit for execution of a django view. i.e. a view never takes more than say, 10secs for execution and if it does, it should return half way from execution. My idea is that we can have a decorator. But i am not sure. Looking for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh look! Over here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to consider using Celery, which includes built in [time limit support](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits) for tasks, and would keep your django app and server responsive:

> A single task can potentially run forever, if you have lots of tasks
>   waiting for some event that will never happen you will block the
>   worker from processing new tasks indefinitely. The best way to defend
>   against this scenario happening is enabling time limits.